# Check if point in GIS polygon fails to produce correct output

Tags: python, geopandas, point-in-polygon

I've tried many, many many, ways to find out if a point is in a GIS polygon based on many great posts, but I can't get any to work properly.  Specifically I created a grid of points covering the bounding box of Japan, and now I want to keep only the ones that are actually over Japan.

Here is one way I tried to get a GIS shapefile for Japan:

```
world = gp.read_file(gp.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
JapanShapes =  world[world.name == "Japan"]
geoJapanShapes = gp.GeoDataFrame(JapanShapes2)
geoJapanShape = geoJapanShapes['geometry'].unary_union
```

I have millions of point data in a geodataframe, but here's just one point (Tokyo station).

```
allCoords = pd.DataFrame([[35.6812,139.7671]], columns=["lat","lon"])
allCoords['geometry'] = allCoords.apply(lambda row: "POINT ("+str(row.lat)+" "+str(row.lon)+")", axis=1)
allCoords = gp.GeoDataFrame(allCoords)
allCoords['geometry'] = allCoords['geometry'].apply(wkt.loads)
```

Now, if test whether Tokyo station is in Japan:

```
print(allCoords['geometry'][0].within(geoJapanShape))
>>>> False
```

However, the last time I checked Tokyo station was within Japan.  And if I do:

```
coordsWithinJapan = allCoords[allCoords.apply(lambda row: row['geometry'].within(geoJapanShapes), axis=1)]
>>>> AttributeError: ("'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute '_geom'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Based on several other posts I also tried:

```
from geopandas.tools import sjoin
gridWithinJapan = sjoin(geoHexData, geoJapanShapes, how='left', op='within')
```

Which just returns every point in the original data.  If I try with the `inner` option I instead get an empty dataframe.

So both methods (kinda) run on my data, but neither method is working to accurately report whether a point is within the boundary. Other versions gave me `crs` errors, but I don't how to deal with that considering my points are hand-made.  Another had a problem because maybe/apparently that shapefile is a multipolygon, which it couldn't handle.  No matter what I try, I seem to be doing something wrong, but I can't find the error.

> How do I actually determine whether my points are in my shape?

Comment: Have you tried leveraging the `contains` function to add a point when `True` or the `intersect` function? One thing I noticed is that you created a point in DataFrame using Pandas, so what if you try declaring it a GeoDataFrame first?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your coordinates (or at least with the example): (35.6812,35.6812) is not located in Japan, but somewhere in the sea: https://www.google.be/maps/place/35%C2%B040'52.3%22N+35%C2%B040'52.3%22E/@35.7119699,35.4862096,9.25z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d35.6812!4d35.6812

Comment: @joris: yeah, that's for pointing it out.  It was a copy and paste error from my workbook.  I've fixed the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Geopandas docs](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html) mention coordinates should be created as a tuple of **Longitude and Latitude** (not latitude and longitude). Switching your lat/lon will give you the result you are expecting.

I was not able to run your code completely because I'm not sure what `wkt.loads` is, but the following is similar and returns `True` as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gp
from shapely.geometry import Point

world = gp.read_file(gp.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
JapanShapes =  world[world.name == "Japan"]
geoJapanShapes = gp.GeoDataFrame(JapanShapes)
geoJapanShape = geoJapanShapes['geometry'].unary_union

TokyoStation = Point(139.7671, 35.6812)

print(geoJapanShape.intersects(TokyoStation))
True
print(TokyoStation.intersects(geoJapanShape))
True
```

Comment: Yeah, I found my error an hour before you answered my question.  Good catch.  BTW, the `wkt.loads` is used to convert strings of geometries (such those saved in csv files) and convert them into actual geometries.  Very useful.